# Why does Spark report "error: not found: type Properties" when loading a data set?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 2.1.0 on Windows 10, I am following the [Spark programming guide to load data using JDBC from MySQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases). When I try to load data using the second method in the link, I get the following error.

```
scala> val connectionProperties = new Properties()
<console>:44: error: not found: type Properties
       val connectionProperties = new Properties()
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `import java.util.Properties`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html.

Comment: Reported an issue as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20138 in Spark's JIRA.